# What is the url parameter for Master Detail using @Url.Action helper when hosting in IIS 7.5 ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I am using jqgrid and advanced master detail approach. It was working fine until I hosted the ASP.NET MVC3 application in IIS 7.5. Currently, my url paramter looks like below

```
jQuery("#list").jqGrid('setGridParam', { url: "/Home/GetNames/" + rowid, page: 1 });
```

which was calling the controller perfectly with the passed rowid.

After I hosted the application in IIS, I learnt that I need to use @Url.Action and I changed my url parameter as below:

```
jQuery("#list").jqGrid('setGridParam', { url: '@Url.Action("GetNames", "Home")' + rowid, page: 1 });
```

Now, my controller is not getting called. I think I am using a wrong syntax when using @Url.Action.

Please provide any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a backslash between rowid and your route

```
jQuery("#list").jqGrid('setGridParam', { url: '@Url.Action("GetNames", "Home")' + "/" + rowid, page: 1 });
```

Comment: Awesome, it worked. Thanks for saving me lot of time. Thanks!

Comment: @inspiringmyself great! glad I can help! don't forget to mark the answer as correct for future reference :)

Comment: Yeah, I tried marking it as an answer as soon as I added the comment and it said it I need to wait 24 seconds, I don't know why. Anyways, glad to up vote for a quick answer.

Comment: @inspiringmyself yeah I think they have a time constraint of some sort! thanks!!